# Restore tabs Bug in new version of Chrome or Mojave?

Tags: google-chrome, restore, browser-tabs

I just upgraded to Mojave 10.14.5 beta 18f131a. On starting Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit), it lost all my tabs. I pressed restore previous session, which showed 64 tabs.  Nothing happened.

History is still there but no "64 tabs"  Shift-command T doesnt help and neither does right clicking in the spare space on the tabs area.

Anything else I can try?